# how Create a exception in Authorization tag in web.config

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, web, web-config

How i create a exception in location to allow access to page GanttViewer.aspx with other rol and others pages only with Admin rol

```
<location path="Admin">
 <system.web>
  <authorization>
   <allow roles="Admin"/>
   <deny users="*"/>
  </authorization>
 </system.web>
</location>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Specify another Location section as you have above with the path specified all the way down to the file.

For each location define the different authorization rules required.